# how to intersect a mult-dimensional array

Tags: php, intersect

i'm building a search engine for my site. I have an index of all the words contained in the pages of my site and their positions. I am using php arrays, and the info returned after a search looks like this:

```
'jeff' => 
    array
      1 => 
        array
          0 => int 0
          1 => int 259
          2 => int 444
          3 => int 461
          4 => int 486
'seka'
    array
      1 => 
        array
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 260
          2 => int 445
          3 => int 462
          4 => int 487
```

If i want to find all the postings list of jeff, i will look for "jeff" as a key; if it exists, then i insert it into a variable, like `$v=index['jeff']`.

Thats simple, but now what if i have a multi string query like "jeff and seka"? How do i check if they exist both and return them as different arrays (one for jeff and another for seka) so i can easily intersect them to find the document with both search strings?

Comment: One quick way is to return values required into some other variable.

Comment: what if the querry string is more than two words lets say five words can you please specify how i will grab the results into valuables?

Comment: If i'm not wrong, those numbers are the page id's where the words have been found. In fact, they point to an array of positions (the int's). The example is not really understandable, but i got it like that :D

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** re-written after comments. Some feedback would be good, to see if we're going in the right direction!

Have you looked at the [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) function? You should be able to do:

```
$common = array_intersect_key(index['jeff'], index['seka']);
```

This will give you a new array with just the keys (and values from 'jeff') of those pages common to Jeff and Seka. You can supply any number of additional arrays to the function, which will allow you to search for (for example) five different terms together and only retrieve pages which contain all five.

Your return array will contain a key for each page. Each key's value will come from the first argument in the `array_intersect_key()` call ("jeff", in my example). In other words, a subset of the `index['jeff']` array is returned.

If you want to retrieve the positions of other terms on each page, you can either repeat the search with different terms at the start (don't: quite inefficient) or loop through the keys in your returned results (you can get an array of the keys with `$pages = array_keys($common);`) and use this as in index to the arrays for each of the other terms.

Comment: ok maybe my explanation wasnt clear but i am building a search engine for a site and at this point i have built an index of all words on pages within the site. the example of jeff and seke are the words extracted from the pages and the numbered array are the ids of the pages where those words were found and the last number values are the positions of the word in the pages.

Comment: The OP was asking for an "AND" comparison, so the intersection already gives the needed info (pages which contains -all- terms in search). This way, he can provide a list of links to those pages as a result for the search submitted by the user. To retrieve position for other terms, i support your idea of just looping through keys in the other words' arrays and retrieve the position numbers.

Comment: @Erenor: I've given an "AND" result and the OP also wanted "different arrays" for jeff and seka as part of his results, which I've addressed (albeit, I may have guessed incorrectly at exactly what was wanted). I entirely agree with your assessment of why he might need the pages on which all the search words occur (I've come across the term "search engine" before)... are you suggesting I've missed something? If so, what?

Comment: @BobSammers sorry for writing late; i think your answer is very good for this question: in fact, the OP was asking how to get the two arrays separately to intersect them and retrieve pages with "both search strings". I suppose the OP hasn't a clear idea of what he needs, since the arrays are already somewhat "separated" and are ready to be used. Of course, a proper search engine would behave in a different way..but we are here to answer questions :P

Comment: hello guys thanks for all you replys, am  sorry my explanation is not good buut my idea was a way of getting different array for jeff and seka so i can intersect them as stated by bob. its simple if only i knew how many words would the querry be but in this case i only have to loop through the search key words first to see how many words i have then loop through my index to get results. lets asume the search keys are jeff and seka the results of the index loop will be an array of results with values array jeff and array seka. The question how do i intersect the two arrays which are 2 in 1